# How to manually built ndk-build (shared library) in existing android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, ndk-build

I have an existing android studio project. I have made shared library named *libtst.so* using ndk with proper jni functions. I have put the library in the following directory
"src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libtst.so"

But while running the project **System.loadLibrary("tst");** cannot work showing following message.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.example.safia.test3-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libtst.so"
                                                                       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                       at com.example.safia.test3.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:62)
                                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
```

I am using android studio 2.3.2.